# Off-grid solar system

Tags: power-supply

I'm doing a project on designing an off-grid PV system to power a constant load at 900W at 12V, 24/day.

If I choose PV systems that are rated at 48 V or any other voltage will that mean that any layout will not be sufficient to power the load at 12V? Will it create problems as such or anything? I am using an MPP charge controller and it is backed by a battery system.

Any book recommendations are welcome as I want to improve on the field.

Comment: It would be simpler to choose a 12 V PV system, if your needs are solely 12 V. Otherwise, you may need to provide a DC to DC *buck* converter capable of your power delivery needs, as well. You should write more about the circumstances -- more than one sentence, anyway.

Comment: Much more detail needed. I assume this is for a course etc - not a real world system? What location (it matters). How many days without sun must it operate for? Is there any backup power source (alternator etc?). What sort of batteries? How far from panels to load. || IF you are using an MPPT controller then 12V or 48V system is not too important load wise - a 48V in 12V out MPPT controller is not unusual. || 900W x 24 H = 21.6 kWh/day . In many locations winter susn is 2-3 hours/day of equivalent full sun. So your PV system needs to be 8 to `2 x as many Watts as your load. ...

Comment: eg 900W x 24 hrs = 21.6 kWh. To obtain 21.6 kWh in 3 hours PV system must store more than 21.6/3  = 7.2 kWh per hour or >= 7.2 kW panels. . Allowing for battery charge efficiency, conversion efficiency, MPPT efficiency ... you'd need 10-12 kW of PV panels. For 2 hours per day full sun equivalent (many locations in winter_) you'd need 50% more again - say 15 kW of PV panels !!!!. | That's for ONE day of 24 hr use. For say 3 sunless days you need 3x that = say 30-45 kW of panels [!!!!]. Battery also gets "interesting". MORE DETAILS PLEASE.

Answer (score 1):

Please provide as much detail as possible.
I assume this is for a course etc - and not a real world system?

What is the location (it matters)?.
How many days without sun must it operate for?
Is there any backup power source (alternator etc?).
What sort of batteries?
How far from panels to load.

IF you are using an MPPT controller then 12V or 48V system is not too important load wise - a 48V in 12V out MPPT controller is not unusual. However, the system you need is a substantial one. As shown below you need 10 to 15 kW of panels!. At 12V that's 850 to 1625 Amps [!!!]. You do not want a 12V system.  Even at 48V that's 215 - 400 Amps. An even higher voltage system may be in order.

900W x 24 H = 21.6 kWh/day.
In many locations winter sun is 2-3 hours/day of equivalent full noonday sun.
So your PV system needs to be 8 to 12 x as many Watts as your load.

eg 900W x 24 hrs = 21.6 kWh.
To obtain 21.6 kWh in 3 hours a PV system must store more than 21.6/3  = 7.2 kWh per hour or >= 7.2 kW panels.
Allowing for battery charge efficiency, conversion efficiency, MPPT efficiency ... you'd need 10-12 kW of PV panels.
For 2 hours per day full sun equivalent (many locations in winter_) you'd need 50% more again - say 15 kW of PV panels !!!!.

That's for ONE day of 24 hr use. For say 3 sunless days you need 3x that = say 30-45 kW of panels [!!!!]. Battery also gets "interesting".

MORE DETAILS PLEASE.

Comment: first off, the location is malawi and in wintertime there is 4.32kwh/m2/day

Comment: and the max days without sun is 2 day, i have derived what you guys mentioned above, my question is basically if i were to modele the PV system by an existing PV panel such as a 300W monocrystaline panel, with give Voltage an Amperes at MPP of 32.4V and 9.26A respectively, would that be able to power my DC load at 12V or it wouldn't match?

Comment: i mean, if i were to directly attach the load to the PVs, then the PV system wouldn't work at MPP, so how do i go around that by using a charge controller and a battery? i considered Tesla powerwall due to high efficiency, discharge capacity etc. Does the battery also need to match such load? or will load ''demand'' and ''get'' what is needed by the batter?

Comment: no there is no backup generator, its completely off-grid, so i tried modelling it according to winter thus i will also need a dumping mechanism for summer radiation levels

Comment: by considering all the efficiencies together i figured i need about 45.96kWh for storage. Its just that i dont think its logicall to throw in any PV system without considering configurations to match my load. or is it possible?

Comment: yes its for a coursework, am not trying to cheat , its just that i don't know about how this exactly works, but i would like to work in such field so am asking for advice

Comment: do i have to use a dc/dc converter to step down my voltage?

Comment: @ChristosEfstathiou  Where in Malawi - Lilongwe shows an interesting double dip in insolation - maybe due to the wet season [**HERE**](https://www.gaisma.com/en/location/lilongwe.html). | Thanks for the extra information. Please add anything relevant to your question as comments can vanish. || You **MUST** use a MPPT controller (or close equivalent) to get anything like full energy from a PV panel. Otherwise the panels waste much of their energy. A "12V" panel makes about 18V at MPP to allow for efficiency, diode,  battery boost charge capability etc. ...

Comment: SO if battery is at 12V and panel at 18V then direct connect efficiency is 12/18 = 66% - you waste ~= 1/3 of your energy. A MPPT controller IS a DC-DC converter and will charge a battery at 12V from an eg 18V source at perhaps around 90% efficiency (depends on brand etc).

 Powerwall looks after all this for you - at a cost and hides details from you. Also note that lead acid batteries MUST NOT be deep discharged for long life. Maybe only 20% of capacity can be used. More occasionally....

Comment: So a ~= 10 kWh/day load at 50% overall PV to load efficiency and 2 day capacity at say even 75% max discharge may need 10 kW x 1/50% x 2 days x 100/(100-75) = 10 x 2 x 2 x 4 = 160 kWh of storage !!!. Rather large.

Comment: so basically, i have to model my array to increase PV to load efficiency, the location in near Lilongwe, Can i safely assume right now that i need to choose a different kind of PV? the other thing i thought off, and someone mentioned, is using a buck converter which i read can have very high efficiencies, to model the voltage and therefore current, then charging the battery and using a charge controller to control load supply at the constant discharge rate required, by the way thanks a lot for the help, If you have any book recommendations about electronics i would happily give them a look

Comment: i think im still going for the Powerwall if it can minimise my losses, in its datasheet it has an internal voltage of 50V so i think i could get away with 50something volts propably

Comment: DO NOT EXCEED the advisable Powerwall Vin specs. There is no need.  That's a decreased mark in an assignment and magic smoke in real life. There are many PV panels around. There will be ones to suit the Powerwall spec. You will need to find a full Powerwall installation deecription. You need a solar-inverter-charger between PV and powerwall (probably). || An MPPT controller IS a buck or a boost-buck inverter. ||...

Comment: Googling [solar system design](https://www.google.com/search?ei=zqmFXMS4CIb_rQGs-4-ACA&q=solar+system+design+&oq=solar+system+design+&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l10.580672.580672..582970...0.0..0.162.162.0j1......0....2j1..gws-wiz.......0i71.WoShG7FAUbA) should provide hours of interesting reading :-).

Comment: @RussellMcMahon -     In your comment, you said, "An MPPT controller IS a buck or a boost-buck inverter. "  Why is MPPT buck or boost-buck, but never boost?

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD Yes. My main point was that if you have an MPPT controller you do not also need a voltage converter separately. Could also be boost only. The most used cases are a high voltage string  being down converted to a battery (as here) or to a mains AC producer.  Buck-boost tracks a battery with a panel string that is probably usually above the battery (buck) but at end of day or in cloud is boosting (at low power). Boost only would be eg low voltage panel to higher voltage battery  or direct to mains. Both are less likely. Higher string voltage is generally more efficient.

Comment: PV to mains at low string voltage can happen, but people usually like to run as high a strng voltage as the inverter will accept. Mainly bacause copper losses are inversely proportional to voltage squared (due to being proportional to current squared. Doubel Vstring and copper losses drop to 25% for same conductors etc. .

Comment: Yet I have heard that microinverters make sense, lower string voltage (line level) combined with better independence from partial or complete shading of individual panels. Still true?

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD  Yes, but ... :-) . There are various approaches. Many installations still use high voltage strings. Microinverters partially gain the same advantage of low current by converting to higher voltage (mains 110 VAC or 230 VAC) at the panel. They alo have the advantages that you state.  They are almost always designed for single panel input - maybe 2 series panels . Enphase, a market leader, has a 38-43 V MPP tracking range !. The search in the next comment shows some units with mybe 20-70V Vin ranges. Many are lower.

Comment: I suspect that in many cases minimum capital cost would be with a centralised larger inverter.  Microinverter advantages make then desirable for other reasons.  As you mentioned plus eg panel shading resilience and ... . || [Google search [Microinverter input voltage](https://www.google.com/search?q=microinverter+input+voltage&rlz=1C1CHBF_enNZ834NZ839&oq=microinverter+input+voltage&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOTIJCAEQIRgKGKABMgkIAhAhGAoYoAHSAQkxMTA3MGoxajSoAgCwAgA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)